# What is the Memory model of DVM or ART in Android

Tags: android, jvm, dalvik, android-runtime

I could not find any docs related to Memory model of DVM or ART. Since DVM is based on register instead of stack so there should be some difference in Memory Model too.

Please explain the memory model of DVM with supporting docs.